# Getting json-format from api into useful json-format (flask)

Tags: python, json, api, flask

I want to insert data from json-format into a webapp through flask to put values into html:

spec_player.html:

```
{% for p in posts: %}
    <p>{{p.first_name}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

1. This works (main.py):

```
posts = [
    {
        "id":237,"first_name":"LeBron","height_feet":6,"height_inches":8,"last_name":"James","position":"F",
        "team":{"id":14,"abbreviation":"LAL","city":"Los Angeles","conference":"West","division":"Pacific","full_name":"Los Angeles Lakers","name":"Lakers"},"weight_pounds":250
    }
]

@app.route("/spec")
def spec_player():
    return render_template("spec_player.html", posts=posts)
```

2. This doesn't work (main.py):

```
posts = [
    {
        "data":[{"id":237,"first_name":"LeBron","height_feet":6,"height_inches":8,"last_name":"James","position":"F",
        "team":{"id":14,"abbreviation":"LAL","city":"Los Angeles","conference":"West","division":"Pacific","full_name":"Los Angeles Lakers","name":"Lakers"},"weight_pounds":250}],
        "meta":{"total_pages":1,"current_page":1,"next_page":null,"per_page":25,"total_count":1}
    }
]

@app.route("/spec")
def spec_player():
    return render_template("spec_player.html", posts=posts)
```

I wonder if there is a way to get the 2. json-format into the  1. format? (I only get the 2. json-format from an api)
**OR**
writing an other query inside html (something like p.data.first_name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always retrieve input data in second format you can transform it to first format like this:

```py
import itertools
flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable

def transform(posts):
    transformed = list(map(lambda post: post["data"], posts))
    flat_posts = list(flatten(transformed))
    return flat_posts
```

example:

```
posts = [
    {
        "data":[{"id":237,"first_name":"LeBron","height_feet":6,"height_inches":8,"last_name":"James","position":"F",
        "team":{"id":14,"abbreviation":"LAL","city":"Los Angeles","conference":"West","division":"Pacific","full_name":"Los Angeles Lakers","name":"Lakers"},"weight_pounds":250}],
        "meta":{"total_pages":1,"current_page":1,"next_page":None,"per_page":25,"total_count":1}
    }
]

print(transform(posts))

>>> [
  {
    'id': 237, 'first_name': 'LeBron', 'height_feet': 6, 'height_inches': 8, 'last_name': 'James', 'position': 'F', 
    'team': {'id': 14, 'abbreviation': 'LAL', 'city': 'Los Angeles', 'conference': 'West', 'division': 'Pacific', 'full_name': 'Los Angeles Lakers', 'name': 'Lakers'}, 'weight_pounds': 250
  }
]
```

Comment: This works pretty well. Is it possible to keep the [ ] in which the data is inside? I need them to access the variables.

Comment: @fid I'm not sure I understand what you asking for, could you please paste somewhere example what you want to achieve?

Comment: I need the form like this: `[{"id":237,"first_name":"LeBron","height_feet":6,"height_inches":8,"last_name":"James","position":"F", "team":{"id":14,"abbreviation":"LAL","city":"Los Angeles","conference":"West","division":"Pacific","full_name":"Los Angeles Lakers","name":"Lakers"},"weight_pounds":250}]` So the squared brackets should stay.

Comment: Looks like it's the same format as format-1 in your post. If you need without flatten, like this: ```[[{'id': 237, 'first_name': 'LeBron', 'height_feet': 6, 'height_inches': 8, 'last_name': 'James', 'position': 'F', 'team': {'id': 14, 'abbreviation': 'LAL', 'city': 'Los Angeles', 'conference': 'West', 'division': 'Pacific', 'full_name': 'Los Angeles Lakers', 'name': 'Lakers'}, 'weight_pounds': 250}]]
``` , then just remove `flatten` call (in transform function)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is filter and flatten the 2nd `posts` JSON before passing into rendering the template. For example, you could do;

```
def fatten(json):
    flatten_json = []
    for node in json:
        d = node["data"]
        if d is not None:
            for item in d:
                flatten_json.append(item)
    return flatten_json
```

Or more Pythonic (but not so readable) version

```
def flatten(json):
    return [item for node in json if node["data"] is not None for item in node["data"]]
```

Then pass the flattened json as

```
return render_template("spec_player.html", posts=fatten(posts))
```

Both functions iterate over posts JSON and extract child nodes in each `data` node.

I don't think pulling a library for this simple task is worth it.